# Prove that $\Phi(Ax)= A.\Phi (x) \forall A\in SO_3(\mathbb R) \ and \ x\in \mathbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let, $V$ be a space of $3\times 3$ skew-symmetric real matrices. Let, $\Phi: \mathbb R^3\to V$ is a map by $$\Phi \begin{pmatrix} u \\ v \\ w\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & w & -v \\ -w & 0 & u \\ v & -u & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
Let, $SO_3(\mathbb R) \curvearrowright \mathbb R^3$ by $A.x=Ax \forall A\in SO_3(\mathbb R) \ and \  x\in \mathbb R^3$(The ususal action) and   $SO_3(\mathbb R) \curvearrowright V$ by $A.M= AMA^t$.

Now prove that $\Phi(Ax)= A.\Phi (x) \forall A\in SO_3(\mathbb R) \ and \ x\in \mathbb R^3$

$\textbf{My attempts:}$
$\Phi$ is a $\mathbb R$ linear map. I am taking $\{e_1,e_2.e_3\}$ as standard basis for $\mathbb R^3$. So for any $x\in \mathbb R^3$, $x=ue_1+ve_2+we_3$ where $u,v,w\in \mathbb R$ So, $\Phi(x)=u\Phi(e_1)+v\Phi(e_2)+w\Phi(e_3)$, so it is sufficient to work with the basis of $\mathbb R^3$.

So, $A.\phi (e_1)= A\Phi(e_1)A^t=A\Phi(e_1)A^{-1}=A\Phi(e_1)Adj(A)$, Since, $det(A)=1$.

But now I am stuck. Any hints will be very much helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is $M$ and why is $AM=AMA^\top$ ? To me that looks wrong.

Comment: @KurtG. $M\in V$ and the group action $SO_3(\mathbb R)\curvearrowright V$ by $A.M=AMA^t$ is well defined. Because it satisfies the two properties of group action:
(1) Since, the identity matrix $I_{3\times 3} \in SO_3(\mathbb R)$, so, $I.M=IMI^t=M$ and (2) for $A,B\in SO_3(\mathbb R)$ , $(AB).M=A.(BM) \forall m\in V$

Comment: Sorry missing type: $\forall M\in V$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the conjugation $A.M:=AMA^\top$ is the action of $A\in SO(3)$ on $M\in V$ (the space of skew symmetric matrices). That little dot is quite important. Probably better to think of another notation. When you check the equation $A.\Phi(x)=\Phi(Ax)$ for the first basis vector you will get
$$
A\Phi(e_1)=
A\left(\begin{matrix}0&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&-1&0\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}
0&-a_{13}&a_{12}\\
0&-a_{23}&a_{22}\\
0&-a_{33}&a_{32}\\   
\end{matrix}\right),
$$

\begin{eqnarray}
A\Phi(e_1)A^\top&=&\left(\begin{matrix}
-a_{13}a_{12}+a_{12}a_{13}&-a_{13}a_{22}+a_{12}a_{23}&-a_{13}a_{32}+a_{12}a_{33}\\
-a_{23}a_{12}+a_{22}a_{13}&-a_{23}a_{22}+a_{22}a_{23}&-a_{23}a_{32}+a_{22}a_{33}\\
-a_{33}a_{12}+a_{32}a_{13}&-a_{33}a_{22}+a_{32}a_{23}&-a_{33}a_{32}+a_{32}a_{33}
 \end{matrix}\right)\\[5mm]
&=&\left(\begin{matrix}
0&-a_{13}a_{22}+a_{12}a_{23}&-a_{13}a_{32}+a_{12}a_{33}\\
-a_{23}a_{12}+a_{22}a_{13}&0&-a_{23}a_{32}+a_{22}a_{33}\\
-a_{33}a_{12}+a_{32}a_{13}&-a_{33}a_{22}+a_{32}a_{23}&0
 \end{matrix}\right)\\[5mm]
&=&\Phi\left(\begin{matrix}
-a_{23}a_{32}+a_{22}a_{33}\\
-a_{12}a_{33}+a_{13}a_{32}\\
-a_{13}a_{22}+a_{12}a_{23}
\end{matrix}\right)
\end{eqnarray}
This should equal
$$
\Phi(Ae_1)=\Phi\left(\begin{matrix}a_{11}\\a_{21}\\a_{31} \end{matrix} \right)
$$
because the columns and rows of $A$ are orthogonal and that matrix has determinant one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you please tell me why the last two lines are the same? I mean why $a_{11}= -a_{23}a_{32}+a_{22}a_{33}$ etc. ?
The determinant of $A$ is $a_{11}(-a_{23}a_{32}+a_{22}a_{33})-a_{21}(a_{12}a_{33}+a_{13}a_{32})+a_{31}(-a_{13}a_{22}+a_{12}a_{23})$. And $det(A)=1$
And, it is clear that since $A\in SO_3(\mathbb R)$ so, the inner product of the first column is $1$, So, $a_{11}^2+a_{21}^2+a_{31}^2=1$

Comment: To save some time and to leave something to do for you I verified this only numerically in a couple of examples (python is a great tool to do that).  Also: The pairwise inner product of all rows and all columns are either zero or one - as we know.